# Do Web Browsers Download the Entire .ICO File If It Contains Multiple Resolutions?

Tags: browser, ico

I have an .ico file that contains every resolution from 16px to 256px.  I have another version of the same .ico file with just 16px and 32px resolutions.  My second file is much smaller than the first.

Do modern web browsers download the entire .ico file or do they only download the largest resolution they use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser will download the full .ico file.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the .ico file in all possible sizes available is downloaded.
Take a look at this [site](http://www.visualpharm.com/office_space_icon_set/) for example, each .ico file contains 4 different resolutions. I hope I could help you :)